# Не добавляется иконка на сайт

Tags: html, html5, веб-программирование, flask

[image: вот мои папки]
[image: это то, как я подключал]

так как это html в консоли ошибок нет, сделал смотря ответы на форумах.
помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Скачивал иконку в формате .ico

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: как вы иконку добавили в код страницы?

Comment: методом <link rel="img/icon.ico" type="icon"/>, <link rel="img/icon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>

Comment: Что для index.html является корнем сайта? Если текущее место, то img не нужен.

Comment: Логичный вопрос — что вы предприняли для того, чтобы ваш веб-сервер по указанной вами относительной ссылке `img/icon.ico` отдавал файл? И относительно чего вы указали ссылку?